# Insufficient privileges to complete the operation for getMemberObjects

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am getting access denied when trying the below request:

Request:

[LINK](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/getMemberObjects)

```
 { "securityEnabledOnly": "true" }
```

I used a `v2.0 auth` endpoint to get my access token, which had the following scopes: (User.Read User.ReadBasic.All User.ReadWrite). 
According to [this](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_getmemberobjects) just having the `User.Read` scope should have been enough.

This is the response I got back:

```
 { "error": { "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied", "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.", "innerError": { "request-id": "634126b5-afaf-439b-a5aa-8967da633ccf", "date": "2016-08-10T04:15:59" } } }
```

Answer (score 1):

The document is not correct. At present, the scope `User.Read; User.ReadWrite` is not able to call the **getMemberObjects**.

I have reported this issue [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/33).

Comment: So how do i get getMemberObjects?

Comment: You can config the other scopes like `User.Read.All` to use this API.

Comment: NOTE:  user.read.all won't work for this function.  You'll likely need directory.read.all (since this returns the groups, directory roles and administrative units) that the object is a member of - where object could be a user, group, contact or service principal (last 2 are in /beta only).

Answer (score 0):

Actually the whole topic is completely wrong and needs fixing.   It should mirror the information here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#getMemberObjects.  The example requests aren't even valid and cannot be run on the manager link AFAIK.  I've added this information to the [doc issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/411)

As for permissions, for a full result set you would need Directory.Read.All.

Hope this helps,